# C# MongoDB. Добавление новых документов без перезаписи существующих

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, .net-core

Приветствую.
Есть коллекция сущностей в монго. Нужно сделать метод, который будет добавлять только новые сущности, без перезаписи существующих (т.е. Replace с IsUpsert=true не подойдет). Сейчас я получаю все айдишники с базы, потом отнимаю их от добавляемого списка и что осталось уже вставляю через InsertMany. Но по мере роста размера моей БД стоимость операции будет увеличиватся, что не очень хорошо.
Также есть идея обернуть InsertMany в try...except, но не уверен что этот вариант оптимальный.
Помогите пожалуйста.